# Difference between Timeline's stop() and jumpTo("end")

Tags: animation, javafx, javafx-8

Could somebody explain me the difference between `timeline.stop()` and  `timeline.jumpTo("end")`?

Answer (score 1):

`Timeline.stop()` halts the animation and makes sure `Timeline.play()` starts form the beginning of the animation; no more updates for the "current run" are done.

`timeline.jumpTo("end")` goes to the mark `"end"` which is positioned at the end of the animation. This has the same effect as `timeline.jumpTo(timeline.getTotalDuration())`. Any effects of the animation arriving at that time are executed.

You can observe the different behavior in the following example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button("Play / (Stop/Jump)");

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(btn.translateXProperty(), 0d)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), new KeyValue(btn.translateXProperty(), 200d))
    );

    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        if (timeline.getStatus() == Animation.Status.RUNNING) {
//            timeline.jumpTo("end");
            timeline.stop();
        } else {
            timeline.play();
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

`timeline.jumpTo("end")` moves the `Button` to the end point of the animation, `timeline.stop()` stops the `Button` in it's current position.